# BroadcastReceiver не работает с кастомными Action

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast-receiver

Ранее задавал уже подобный вопрос но он всё еще актуален (проблему не решил). А проблема в том что BroadcastReceiver никак не реагирует на мои собственные Action (c системными кстати всё нормально работает). Регистрировал ресиверы и через манифест и програмно, извиняюсь за сленг - ноль на массу.Тестировал на андроид версиях 5—8, не работает нигде. В предыущих проэктах которые я писал делал ровно тоже самое и всё отлично работало. В чем может быть проблема? Может кто то сталкивался с подобным? Заранее спасибо за ответ! И да когда отправляю Broadcast из adb всё работает.

```
public class ExecuteTaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"SSSSSSS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra(AppKeys.TASK_TITLE))
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        0,
                        i,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );

        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
        r.play();
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(12345, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

В манифесте

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.ExecuteTaskReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="packagename.DONE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Создаю Alarm

```
 @Override
    public void createAlarm() {
        Context context = mTaskView.getContext();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppKeys.DONE);

        intent.putExtra(AppKeys.TASK_TITLE, mTask.getTitle());
        context.sendBroadcast(intent); //Отправляю Broadcast но ничего не происходит
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTaskTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Из AppKeys

```
public static final String  DONE = "packagename.DONE";
```

Comment: Через adb пробовали отправлять?

Comment: Через adb нет не пробовал

Comment: Пробуйте. Есть ещё вариант с конфликтом, но я давно программировал на android (Пол года)

Comment: Класс `ExecuteTaskReceiver` точно лежит в отдельном файле в пакете с именем `packagename`? И что говорит `LogCat` во время отправки?

Comment: @MrBin Спасибо) Попробовал через adb и да действительно broadcast приходит, но саму пролему так и не решил. А что там за вариант с конфликтом?

Comment: Пробуй менять название действия. Так же все максимально упростите, т.е. регистрацию через код сделайте, изменениие место хранителя и тд.

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под изменить место хранителя?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема, насколько я помню решил вопрос с регистрацией ивента в коде, а не через манифест. Где нибудь в onCreate зарегистрируйте

```
registerReceiver(new ExecuteTaskReceiver(), new IntentFilter(FILTR!!!));
```

и в onDestroy() делайте

```
unregisterReceiver();
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, по крайней мере для меня это не работает